# Issue with starting nginx after updating site packages

Tags: nginx, redhat

After doing a firmware update on rhel server

```
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Dec 17 12:14:26 mnmmoweb01p.jkhy.com systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 12:14:26 mnmmoweb01p.jkhy.com systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
Dec 17 12:14:26 mnmmoweb01p.jkhy.com polkitd[13138]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:15176:292396 (system bus name :1.107, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale e
Dec 17 12:14:26 mnmmoweb01p.jkhy.com sudo[15175]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

unsure how to troubleshoot polkit, any advice is appreciated

edit: nginx log,

`2019/12/17 13:10:23 [emerg] 30120#30120: module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so" version 1010002 instead of 1017006 in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:1`

Answer (score 0):

Internal nginx conflict, yum remove nginx; yum install nginx resolved the issue